# Localisation of large number symbols (K, M, B, T, etc.)

Tags: javascript, math, localization

Hi there I am busy working on Shortening long numbers in javascript for graphing display purposes, such that a long number like: 12,345,678 becomes: 12.3M

My questions are as follows:

How do I localise this?

Can this be localised?

Does the INTL api have something for dealing with this?

Just to clarify, I have already written JS code to handle all of the BMK stuff and that works fine.  My questions pertain only to the correct way (if any) to localise this.

Also to clarify, I am using the 'modern english' system that does not use things like milliard or billiard, nor do I care for adoption of such things due to their minority.

That being said if someone points me to a localisation solution that already takes care of things like milliard and billiard, etc. then I certainly won't say no.

Comment: you can simply write a js function

Comment: Seems problematic. M often means "million" in modern English, but other languages go "million" "milliard" "billion" "billiard" etc.

Comment: I have clarified my question, pls see ammended info

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Numeral.js maybe. http://numeraljs.com/#locales

Comment: *I am using the 'modern english' system*  Me, I'd use the system established by the SI prefixes.  In other words, no localisation necessary.  Modern english would probably have you using stones, groats and furlongs.

Comment: I have posted an answer that may help; I hope, although late :-)

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) constructor you can format your numbers with localisation as requested.

Here is an example in locales `en` `ar` `fr` `es` `hi`.

```js
let op = {notation:"compact",
          compactDisplay:"short",  // use compact mode
          roundingMode:"ceil",     // rounding mode
          maximumFractionDigits:1  // use 1 decimal place
         };

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB',op).format(12345678));  // → "12.3M"
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es',op).format(12345678));      // → "12,3 M"
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ar',op).format(12345678));     // → "12.3 مليون"
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr',op).format(12345678));     // → "12,3 M"
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hi',op).format(12345678));     // → "1.2 क॰"
```